# How to join two very large tables that won't fit into memory?

Tags: sql, pandas, join, sqlalchemy, batch-processing

I am working with sqlalchemy and I want to join two tables. One table has 500 million rows so my query will time out if I do it all at once. Also I can't work on that table all in memory.

My only option is to do this in batches.

My problem is that I need to join two tables and I can't just take both of the tables in batches, because there is no way to be sure that the corresponding ids are part of the same fetched batch.

Somehow I need to perform this join but I just don't know how without querying at least one of those tables as a whole.

This is my code:

```
        some_table = connector.connect_to_table(metadata=m, table="SOME_TABLE")
        other_table = connector.connect_to_table(metadata=m, table="OTHER_TABLE")

        query = select([some_table.c.id,
                        some_table.c.type,
                        other_table.c.some_other_type]
                       ).join(vehicles_individual_query,
                                      (some_table.c.id== other_table.c.id)
                                      )

        conn = self.engine.connect().execution_options(
                stream_results=True)

        for chunk_dataframe in pd.read_sql(
                query, conn, chunksize=1000):

            print(f"Got dataframe w/{len(chunk_dataframe)} rows")
            # ... do something with dataframe ...
```

So of course, in order to get even 1000 rows as defined per the chunksize, one will still have to process the whole other_table, because of the join condition.

How can I do this in batches?

Comment: Could you write the joined table back into your database using [Insert.from_select](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.from_select), or the table too big for that?

Comment: instead of the hole table make a subselect of 10000 (LIMIT offset)  and join only this rows

Comment: But I would have to take a subselect of 10000 from each table. 10000 from the first and 10000 from the second. The tables are not 1:1 in terms of rows, so there will be joins missing if I just take the first 10000 of A and the first 10000 of B.

Comment: no the join would remove all rows of the second table that don't fit the join condition, 100 is only a number you can try higher numbers, draw back you need multiple queries try it

Comment: What do you mean by "the join would remove all rows of the second table that don't fit the join condition"? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: you make qan inner join of lets say 10000 rows, so it will return 10000 rows (or more when you don't have 1 : 1 relationship) but only those where the ids are equal, because that is the condition, maybe read up on joins

Comment: I know how joins work. It's just that I can't just target the complete table, because it is way too big. As I said it is timing out. So even if I take the first 10000 rows of the first table I still have to join against the complete second table in order not to miss any rows that might satisfy my join condition. If I take the first n rows of table A and the first n rows of table B, the number of joined rows will be greater than n but the number of distinct ids that satisfied the condition is smaller than n. Therefore ids will not be considered if I fetch the next batches.

Comment: "So even if I take the first 10000 rows of the first table I still have to join against the complete second table in order not to miss any rows that might satisfy my join condition." - Yes, but if the second table has an appropriate index on it then the database engine can perform the join using the *index* for the whole second table and only return the *rows* from the second table where the join condition is satisfied.

Comment: Joins are typically pipelined so they won't consume a lot of memory, neither at the server side or at the client side. Therefore, memory won't be an issue. Now, if you are processing 500 million rows, that's going to take time. The db connection of a batch process should not time out, even if it takes hours to process the whole join. Now, are you really SURE you want to join such big tables? What for?